# The view is called but not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a project that has a Q&A format, with questions, answers and question comments and I'm having a problem with this structure. My roadmap is this:

experience profile --> discussions

So, in this project I have a Experience profile with some informations and a link_to for
discussions that aggregate all Q&A structure. My problem is that when I try to access the discussions structure(Q&A) through link_to, nothing is rendered. I'm using Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.3 version. I'd like your help!

**Experience profile(link_to):**

```
<%= link_to "New topic", experience_discussions_path(@experience), :remote => true %></p>
```

**Discussions controller:**

```
respond_to :html, :json
def index
    @experience = Experience.find(params[:experience_id])
    @question = Question.new
    @questions = Question.where(:experience_id => @experience.id).order('updated_at desc')

respond_with(@experience, @questions) do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => !request.xhr? }
end
end

def create
    @experience  = Experience.find(params[:experience_id])
    @question = @experience.questions.new(params[:question])
    @question.user = current_user
if @question.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Pergunta criada com sucesso'
else
    respond_with(@experience, @question) do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to experience_path(@experience)+'#discussion' }
    end
end
```

**Discussions view (index):**

```
<div id="questions">
<%= form_for(@question, :url => experience_discussions_path, :method => 'post') do |f| %><br />
<fieldset class ="new_question">
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Ask question" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => 'button' %>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>

<% @questions.each do |q| %>
<h3 id="q_title">
    <%= (:question) %>: <%= q.title %><br />
    <small> <%= (:question_from) %> <%= q.user %></small>
</h3>

<%= form_for(Answer.new(:question => q),:url => experience_discussion_answers_path(@experience, q),:method => 'post') do |f| %>
<fieldset class="new_answer">
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Resposta" %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => 'button' %>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end if current_user == @experience.user && q.answers.empty? %>

<% q.answers.each do |answer|%> 
    <p><%= answer.body %></p> 
<% end %>

<% q.comments.each do |comment|%>
    <p <%= 'class=owner' if comment.user == @experience.user%> >
    <small><%= user_link comment.user %></small>
    <br>
    <%= comment.body %>
    </p>
<% end unless q.answers.empty? %>  
<%= link_to("Add comment"), experience_discussion_comments_path(@experience, q)) %>
<%= render(:partial => 'question_comment') %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all those respond_to and respond_with code and let rails show some errors, you'll see what's missing there, I guess you need to respond_to format.js on your methods and have .js.erb views too

check the log and see the format of the request that is getting to your server